# What's the error with Symfony 2 after composer installation?

Tags: php, symfony, netbeans

I installed Symfony 2 with Composer and I have error in Netbeans 7.3.1.

/vendor/symfony/symfony/Component/Filesystem/README.md

on line 33:

```
$filesystem->mirror($originDir, $targetDir, \Traversable $iterator = null, $options = array());
```

but if i remove **\Traversable** then error disappears.

I use PHP 5.4 (also in Netbeans). This is problem from PHP or Netbeans? How can I disable this error without remove **\Traversable**?

Comment: Does the error show up when you actually run the code or only in NetBeans?

Comment: Then it's just NetBeans. Maybe you need to set the PHP version in NetBeans somewhere. I don't use it, so I can't help with that.

Comment: If you find out let us know, I have the same issue it's kinda annoying